# Legend of picture, caption

Tags: captions, fancyhdr, legend

I would like to assign one caption to a picture in my report, without this caption begin in the listing of figure.

I use the following:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{minipage}[l]{.645\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.94]{images/4.JPG}
\caption{Yearling inspecté, de profil}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

How can I do that?

(Sorry for my English.)

Comment: Hello there, [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Make yourself at home! `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want your figure to be listed in the table of figures, you can Use `\caption*{Your caption}` after loading the `caption` package:

```
\usepackage{caption}
```

Comment: I tried to do that, I thought that it would be the solution but it is not working.
In this case, the caption is still in the table of figures and * is in my caption !